# Exchanging authorization code for access token with googleapis package in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-authentication

I'm trying to implement a google sign-in for a server-side NodeJS application that needs googledrive access, and can't get the 'googleapis' google object to exchange the authorization code for an actual access token.

There's google documentation for what I want to do [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/server-side-flow), but step 7, which is where I'm stuck, is described in Java and Python, and so the NodeJS google object isn't present. I've also followed the nodeJS quickstart [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/nodejs), but many of the steps for authentication are different. Namely, I can't make a `google.auth.OAuth2` object the same way because the credentials for my application differ in format from the example's (they don't have redirect uris)

This is where I've got it:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const { google } = require('googleapis');



formAuthClient('<PastedAuthCodeFromFrontEnd>');

async function formAuthClient(code) {
  // reads credentials from file
  const credentials = await readFile('./client_secret.json').then(JSON.parse);

  // cannot read redirect_uris like in NodeJS quickstart because these do not exist. 
  // Also, no credentials.installed, it's credentials.web
  const { client_secret, client_id } = credentials.web;
  const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2( // form authObject
    client_id, client_secret
  );
  console.log(oAuth2Client);

  const token = await oAuth2ClientGetToken(oAuth2Client, code).catch(console.err);
  oAuth2Client.setCredentials(token);
  return oAuth2Client;
}


// just an async wrapper for fs.readFile
function readFile(file) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readFile(file, (err, content) => {
      if (err) reject(err);
      resolve(content);
    });
  })
}
// just an async wrapper for oAuth2Client.getToken
function oAuth2ClientGetToken(oAuth2Client, code) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    oAuth2Client.getToken(code, (err, token) => { // errors out here
      if (err) reject(err);
      resolve(token);
    });
  });
}
```

Running this code first prints the oAuth2Client object, and then gives me the following error:

```sh
OAuth2Client {
  _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
  _eventsCount: 0,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  transporter: DefaultTransporter {},
  credentials: {},
  certificateCache: {},
  certificateExpiry: null,
  certificateCacheFormat: 'PEM',
  refreshTokenPromises: Map {},
  _clientId: '<probablySecretClientID>.apps.googleusercontent.com',
  _clientSecret: '<defSecretClientSecret>',
  redirectUri: undefined,
  eagerRefreshThresholdMillis: 300000
}


(node:16186) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: invalid_grant
    at Gaxios.request (/home/miko/node/clouds/api/node_modules/gaxios/build/src/gaxios.js:70:23)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:89:5)
    at async OAuth2Client.getTokenAsync (/home/miko/node/clouds/api/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/oauth2client.js:119:21)
(node:16186) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:16186) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code
```

Ideally, I'd want the top function to return a fully authenticated client object that I can later use to access google drive apis

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a solution here https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/issues/1951

For all thows that come after me - Resolution
Prerequisites
If you have the same setup as me where your performing the exchange for to token not in the frontend browser react code but in a back end setup. I did the following things which seems to resolve the issue.

1> Add the secondary hostname/port in the Google Cloud platform > APIs& Services > Credentials> (your oauth ClientID.) > Authorised JavaScript origins. with your web apps URI.

for example, if you have localhost:3000 serving your react code and localhost:3002. You need to ad both. This applies to your production setup as well.

2> The authorization code is one time use only. Once you use it, if your did not store the refresh token/access token. You need to ask the user to auth again. It gives the precise same message.

3> There seems to be a time out on how long you can hold the Authorization token. Google can answer this better than me, however I noticed I got the same error if I stored a working legitimate Authorization token for more than an hour and it gave me the same message as above.

My advise is send back better erroring than data: { error: 'invalid_grant', error_description: 'Bad Request' },

Since all the above scenarios seem to have caused the same error. It was hard for me to debug.